# How can I know what rows are visibile within a WPF DataGridView?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, rows, visible

Is there a way to determine what data grid rows/cells are being show in the WPF DataGrid within the scrollviewer's bounds at any one time?

Comment: You could look into the [LoadingRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.loadingrow.aspx) event, but you may have to create something more complex if that doesn't work. For instance, you may have to iterate each DataGridRow and check its Visibility/IsVisible or DataContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look into the LoadingRow event, but you may have to create something more complex if that doesn't work. For instance, you may have to iterate each DataGridRow and check its Visibility/IsVisible or DataContext.

;)